# Souffle datalog: Stop execution when one record of a relation exists

Tags: static-analysis, datalog

Is there a way to make souffle stop execution when one record of a relation is found (for example, say I have .decl relationA(x:number), and we find one record relationA(some number) then execution stops). Otherwise, is it not possible to make souffle flush relations to disk before execution finishes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have  your "some number" beforehand
you may be able to reduce the program output
by using the Magic Set feature.

https://souffle-lang.github.io/magicset